# compare two dictionary and find missing keys

Tags: python

I have two nested dictionaries in a single file . I want to compare those two nested dictionaries and find the missing keys in each of the dictionary

I tried this,

```
for key, value in json2.items():
        current_path = path + "." + key
        if key not in json1:
            missing_data[current_path] = value
        elif isinstance(value, dict) and isinstance(json1[key], dict):
            missing_in_nested = missing(json1[key], value, current_path)
            missing_data.update(missing_in_nested)

    return missing_data
```

but it will also gives the missing values. but I only want the missing keys.

Comment: Please provide a sample of what your json1 and json2 would look like as well as the expected output.

Comment: Than don't add `value` to `missing_in_nested`?

Answer (score 0):

you add the value yourself with

```
if key not in json1:
    missing_data[current_path] = value
```

if you just want keys either ignore values in your resulting dict or do not create a dict of missing keys at all and instead append them to something like a plain simple list

```
if key not in json1:
    missing_data.append(current_path)
```